# Embedding XML data in existing HTML/CSS template

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt, embed

I want to embed an XML file into an existing template I have been creating. My website contains a content header, content section, sidebar etc. But I want to embed the XML data into the content section, so that I can use my existing CSS and formatting without rewriting half of it in XSLT. I have already run across the "xml" tag, but I want to import it from an external file rather than inline.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="Local  fish and chips bar, serving the city for over 20 years.">
<meta name="keywords" content="Food,Drink,Fish,Chips,British">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<h1>
<img alt="logo" src="images\logo.jpg" style="width:473px;height:135px">Home</h1>
</div>
<div id = "wrap">
    <div id = "navWrap">
    <div id = "nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a class ="nav" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class ="nav" href="order.html">Order Online</a></li>
            <li><a class ="nav" href="look.html">Look Around</a></li>
            <li><a class ="nav" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a class ="nav" href="#menu">Download Our Menu</a></li>
            <li><a class ="nav" href="#contact">Download Our App</a></li>
            <li><a class ="nav" href="report.html">Report</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<div id="main">
<xml Id = msg SRC = "menu.xml"></xml> ----- **XML GOES HERE**
</div>


<div id="sidebar">
<div id = "sidebarMain">
</div>
<div id = "mapWrap">
<iframe src= width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
<h3><center><u>Opening Times</u></center></h3>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Lunch</th>
            <th>Evening</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Monday</td>
            <td>10:00 - 14:00</td> 
            <td>16:00 - 22:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tuesday</td>
            <td>10:00 - 14:00</td> 
            <td>16:00 - 22:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Wednesday</td>
            <td>10:00 - 14:00</td> 
            <td>16:00 - 22:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Thursday</td>
            <td>10:00 - 14:00</td> 
            <td>16:00 - 22:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Friday</td>
            <td>10:00 - 14:00</td> 
            <td>15:00 - 23:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Saturday</td>
            <td>10:00 - 14:00</td> 
            <td>15:00 - 23:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sunday</td>
            <td>Closed</td> 
            <td>Closed</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


<div id = "footer">
Copyright © FryingNemo.com<br>
<br>
</div>
</body>
</head>
```

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="nemoMenu.xsl"?>
<breakfast_menu>

<food>
<name>Belgian Waffles</name>
<price>$5.95</price>
<description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
<calories>650</calories>
</food>

<food>
<name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
<price>$7.95</price>
<description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
<calories>900</calories>
</food>

<food>
<name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
<price>$8.95</price>
<description>Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped                         cream</description>
<calories>900</calories>
</food>

<food>
<name>French Toast</name>
<price>$4.50</price>
<description>Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
<calories>600</calories>
</food>

<food>
<name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
<price>$6.95</price>
<description>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
<calories>950</calories>
</food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

Any resolution on the issue would be appreciated, or perhaps I would be better of simply using XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

Neither HTML 4 nor HTML5 has an `xml` element, only older versions of IE on Windows supported that to embed so called `XML data islands` inline in HTML. So there is no other way to embed external XML documents in an HTML document other than there is to embed other content, namely the `iframe` element and the `object` element. That is as far as static HTML is concerned, of course if you have some server-side programming/processing framework or want to rely on client-side scripting, then there are other options.